# How do you delete a value from a Database through a dropdownlist?

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net, database, vb.net

Basically I'm trying to give the function to the user to delete data relating to a staff member by selecting their name from the dropdown list and clicking done, but I keep getting error messages such as

> "Incorrect syntax near "," "

but Ive put in checkpoints and can see that no value is being picked up so I was wondering would anyone have idea as to where I am going wrong??

```
 Dim Con As SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    Dim recordsAffected As String
    Dim cmdstring As String = "Delete StaffID, FullName, Gender, Age, Driver, StartDate, ContactNumber, Waistcoat WHERE FullName = DropDownList1.SelectedValue"
    Con = New SqlConnection("Data Source=OISINMCGRANN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=YellowDoor;Integrated Security=True")
    cmd = New SqlCommand(cmdstring, Con)
    Con.Open()
    RecordsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Con.Close()
End Sub
```

I've tried this without the dropdownlist in quotations:

```
   Dim Con As SqlConnection
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand
        Dim recordsAffected As String
        Dim cmdstring As String = "Delete StaffID, FullName, Gender, Age, Driver, StartDate, ContactNumber, Waistcoat WHERE FullName =" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue
        Con = New SqlConnection("Data Source=OISINMCGRANN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=YellowDoor;Integrated Security=True")
        cmd = New SqlCommand(cmdstring, Con)
        Con.Open()
        RecordsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Con.Close()
    End Sub
```

Comment: "delete from table name where FullName= ' "+DropDownList1.SelectedValue+" ' " try this, this is not a good practice use parameterized query

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySql the query should be

```
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE some_column = some_value
```

I don't see any table name in your query

```
Delete [FROM TABLE?] WHERE FullName =" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue
```

Comment: sorry yes Im silly I've been playing around with the query so many times that I left it out that time - I just copied your query and add the table and again "Incorrect syntax near ","

Comment: the fullname has to be enclosed between single quotes marks. Delete [FROM TABLE?] WHERE FullName = 'your name'. Also, you are exposed to sql injection, so be aware

Comment: Really tried working on it and still wont work 
'   Dim Con As SqlConnection
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand
        Dim recordsAffected As String
        Dim cmdstring As String = "DELETE [Staff Table](StaffID, FullName, Gender, Age, Driver, StartDate, ContactNumber, Waistcoat) WHERE 'FullName'" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue
        Con = New SqlConnection("Data Source=OISINMCGRANN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=YellowDoor;Integrated Security=True")
        cmd = New SqlCommand(cmdstring, Con)
        Con.Open()
        RecordsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Con.Close()
    End Sub '

Comment: "DELETE From Staff Table WHERE FullName = ' " + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + " ' "; But you have to use parameterized query. This is only for testing

Answer (score 0):

Use parameterized query and avoid [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

```
 Dim cmdstring As String = "Delete from tablename WHERE FullName =@FullName";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FullName",DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
```

or

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@FullName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value =DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
```